# rendering a partial as json returns syntax errors on line breaks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, renderpartial

I have a json object which is created from results from multiple database queries.

I am trying to move the json into a partial so I can use the same json format from multiple methods (index, search).

I had my results in _listResults.js.erb, and have now moved them into results.json.erb and in _listResults.js.erb I have

```
[
<% @results.each_with_index do |result, idx| %>
<%= render 'results.json.erb', result => result %>
<% end %>
]
```

my partial looks like this

```
{"result":<%= result.id %>
,"title":"<%= result.title %>
.....
```

due to the line breaks, I'm getting an error that says

```
... syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end...);@output_buffer.safe_concat(',"title":');@output_buffer.a...
```

Though I could put the entire json output into one line, and it looks like that would resolve the problem, that would really be a pain to maintain if I want to change the output at a later time.

What's the best way to deal with this sort of thing.

I'm on Windows if that matters (hopefully it won't).

Thanks

Comment: The best way is not to construct your JSON manually and use to_json/as_json in your controller to return the proper object.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
{"result":<%= result.id %>,
 "title":"<%= result.title %>"
 ...
```

FYI, http://www.jsonlint.com/ is great site where you can check whether or not your json is valid.

Comment: the problem isn't mis-formed JSON, so jsonlint isn't going to help. This only broke once I put it into a partial. Adding the ',' to the above line only solves the problem until I hit the ':', this is what I meant by my comment of 'I could put the entire json output into one line'.

Comment: Did you even try what I suggest?

Comment: yes, I had tried that before you suggested it, if I follow your format, it breaks at the ':', as I commented. If I move the ':' to the same line, then I'm getting to the point where everything is on one line. It will then break on nested '{'. I figured there was a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the json but with the way the ruby parser works, in this case it needs to have the comma on the same line.

```
[0,
 2
] parses

[0
,2] doesn't
```

change your erb to

```
{
  "result": <%= result.id %>,
  "title": "<%= result.title %>"
}
```

Comment: thanks James, unfortunately, this only works until I hit '{' for a nested object. It doesn't seem to care if that is at the end of a line, or the beginning of the line or anywhere else.

Comment: Mmm I am doing the same thing and the only difference I have is my partial view is .html.erb. it's called _data.html.erb. And from index.html.erb <%= render :partial => 'data' %>

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your original erb file, `result => result` should be `:result => result`.

```
[
<% @results.each_with_index do |result, idx| %>
<%= render 'results.json.erb', :result => result %>
<% end %>
]
```

Comment: I don't think so. :result => result returns an empty set. If I don't include result=>result I get an 'undefined local variable' error.

Comment: `result=>result` is just invalid, render expects an hash of options. With `result=>result` you provide a hash with the same key and value, this is not a valid option.